# What happens to text in TextView object, when its visibility is set to View.GONE?

Tags: android, textview

I have a **TextView** object in an activity(not a fragment) which I fills some text using `SetText()`.  In some point of time, I change the visibility of the **TextView** object to View.GONE. After sometime, when **TextView** object's visibility is set to View.VISIBLE, the text set dynamically is not shown in **TextView**. I tried to understand what happens using Log, and found out that the content of **TextView** object is empty string. Hence my question, What happens to text in **TextView** object, when its visibility is set to View.GONE ?

synopsis:

fill text in **textview** using `setText()` --> change **visibility** to `View.GONE` --> change **visibility** to `View.VISIBLE` --> `getText()` **returns** empty **string**

question : why?

Comment: You sure the `onCreateView()` isn't called again?

Comment: View.GONE should not do that, it just makes the view invisible (and it does not take space). Could you post the code where you're using the textview?

Comment: It was a rookie mistake. TextView's visibility was hidden from the view because of other elements overlapping it,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setVisibility()` is a method of the `View` class and the docs says that when the visibility is set to `View.GONE`:

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
>   purposes.

Hence, the `View` instance (`TextView` object here) is very much alive and thriving and there is no reason for its private fields (`mText` in case of `TextView`) to be destroyed. Its just invisible to the layout manager. In your case one of the culprits for the said behavior is a probable re-initialization of the `TextView` object (via a call to `onCreateView()` for instance).

Comment: What about View.INVISIBLE ?

In my application, I want something which I can manipulate programmatically but it won't show to the user.

Answer (score 1):

**The Textview is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.**
So there is no data loss,it just invisible with no space acquire for layout purposes. so it must be some other setText() operation in your code or may be you recreate TextView object.